# Is it possible to restirct an ssh key to specific directories

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have an account on a server that I need to give sftp access to another person. This person however only needs access to a small subset of directories. Is it possible, without creating another user account, to restrict an ssh key to that subset of directories.

Basically the website on which these directories are located lives within the home directory of a specific user account. I would prefer not to have to create a separate user account just to lock the use down to those directories. If it is possible to lock down the access to specific directories using an ssh key that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but it's sort of a hack. The much preferred, simpler way is just to only grant that user permissions to certain files and directories.

Comment: What about `chroot`'ing your users? Check out this link: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/229

Comment: chrooting the user requires that all of the directories in the path below it be owned by root and not writeable by any other user.

As the directories I want to restrict the user to are part of a website that needs to be updated by a non root account I cannot use chroot for the subdirectories in question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer on how to accomplish your goal using ssh rather than sftp.  This has some chance of being acceptable to the OP because it still uses the ssh tool chain.

This technique is using a feature of ssh that allows ssh to run a command based on the private key presented to host machine.  When the host sees that key, then it runs the associated command.  For the command we will use "cat" which will dump the file.

1. add a line that looks like this to `~mr_user/.ssh/authorized_keys2`

```sh
command="/usr/bin/cat ~/sshxfer/myfile.tar.gz.uu",no-port-forwarding ssh-dss xxxPUBLIC_KEYxxx mr_user@tgtmach
```

2. populate the file like this:

```sh
uuencode -m myfile.tar.gz /dev/stdout >~mr_user/sshxfer/myfile.tar.gz.uu
```

3. transfer the file by being on the target machine and running this:

```
ssh -i ~/keys/privatekey.dsa mr_user@srcmach |sed -e's/
//g' |uudecode >myfile.tar.gz
```

The tricky part to that command is there is a newline in the sed command to remove the newlines from the .uu file.

I did not found a way to pass in a name of a file to transfer, so I had to make a key for each file I wanted to transfer.  This was okay for my use case because I only had two files I wanted to transfer.